# NA from correlation function

Tags: r, correlation

Could you please explain me the difference between these two cases?

```
> cor(1:10, rep(10,10))
[1] NA
Warning message:
In cor(1:10, rep(10, 10)) : the standard deviation is zero

> cor(1:10, 1:10)
[1] 1
```

the first one is just a straight line as well as the second I would expect the correlation to be one. What am I not considering? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plot the data and it should be clear. The data set

```
## y doesn't vary
plot(1:10, rep(10,10))
```

is just a horizontal line. The correlation coefficient [undefined](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_and_dependence) for a horizontal line, since the estimate of the standard deviation for `y` is 0 (this appears on the denominator of the correlation coefficient). While

```
plot(1:10, 1:10)
```

is the line:

```
y = x
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks. I knew that. But I thought that the correlation was not calculated based on the formula relative to my data

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your comment

Comment: I meant that I thought the only thing that mattered was "how much in line" were the points... to my logic I mean. Thanks for the explanation, I'll wrap `cor` into something returning one in such cases

Comment: @Michele That's a terrible idea.

Comment: @Roland why? I just need one for such scenario. I simply need a rough measure of "how much in line" are my points through the time. In case they don't vary I would like to have one.

Comment: The pearson correlation coefficient has the variance of x in the denominator. If you change only the limit case of zero variance in x, it can not be interpreted in the usual way, but still won't really answer your question. You could use something like the residual variance of a linear fit, e.g. `1/(n-p)*sum(lsfit(cbind(1,1:10),rep(10,10))$residuals^2)`.

Comment: @csgillespie `this appears on the denominator of the correlation coefficient` I was looking for something like that thanks a lot. I should give a look to my old stats book of the 1st uni year :-) before making such stupid question... probably I should use something different than `cor` (@Roland) I know, but it worked fine until now, in terms that I'm happy for what it's spotted out thanks to a low value of `cor`.

Comment: @Roland I did't see your last comment when putting mine. Yes, as we both said I should use something different. Thanks for that!!

Comment: @csgillespie just seen your range of courses, very nice, I'd probably need a couple of them at least :-)

Comment: `cor(1:10, rep(10,10))` can not only be the line y=f(x)=x (horizontal line), but could also be the line x=f(y)=y (vertical line).

Comment: @Roland Sorry, what are `n` and `p`? Thanks

Comment: n: number of values, p: number of parameters

Answer (score 1):

If you want to measure how much "in line" the points are, 
you can use (one minus) the ratio of the eigenvalues of the variance matrix.

```
f <- function(x,y) { 
  e <- eigen(var(cbind(x,y)))$values
  1 - e[2] / e[1]
}

# To have values closer to 0, you can square that quantity.
f <- function(x,y) { 
  e <- eigen(var(cbind(x,y)))$values
  ( 1 - e[2] / e[1] )^2
}
f( 1:10, 1:10 )
f( 1:10, rep(1,10) )
f( rnorm(100), rnorm(100) )     # Close to 0
f( rnorm(100), 2 * rnorm(100) ) # Closer to 1
f( 2 * rnorm(100), rnorm(100) ) # Similar
```

It will be 1 if the points are aligned, 
0 if the cloud they form has a spherical shape, 
invariant by translations and rotations,
non-negative, and symmetric.

If your situation is not symmetric, i.e., if `x` and `y` do not play the same role,
the regression-based approach suggested in Roland's comment makes more sense.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the nice method. But yes it's not symmetric `y` is a value measured through the time at not evenly spaced intervals (which may change or not). My question was just related to discover the nature of the `NA`, but it seems worth posting another...