# Most robust way to measure the alignment between points in R

Tags: r, correlation

Until now I used to use `cor` to measure the alignment between points. I am quite happy with the results, values between `-1` and `0` always spot the lines I want. However, thanks to the answers and comments in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17319910/na-from-correlation-function/17320976#17320976), I realised it's not the most robust approach because of the standard deviation being zero for flat lines, such as:

```
> cor(1:10, rep(10,10))
[1] NA
Warning message:
In cor(1:10, rep(10, 10)) : the standard deviation is zero
```

My aim is to define a function which gives `1` for points perfectly aligned (regardless the slope) and values closer to `0` for points not in line. Would you suggest a more robust approach than mine?

EDIT:

following the suggestion of @Hong Ooi I got

```
data1 <- data.frame(date = c(13636, 13636, 14403, 14761, 15201, 15741),
                    value = c(865310, 999989, 999989, 2, 999989, 26))

data2 <- data.frame(date = c(12667, 12745, 13106, 13276, 13461, 13626),
                    value = c(1904, 2055, 2740, 3376, 3567, 4099))

m <- cbind(data1$date, data1$value)
sdev <- prcomp(m)$sdev
sdev[1]/sum(sdev)
# 0.9986399

m <- cbind(data2$date, data2$value)
sdev <- prcomp(m)$sdev
sdev[1]/sum(sdev)
# 0.961
```

However, I was expecting the a very low value for `data1`

[image]

Comment: I think this should be migrated to Cross Validated.

Comment: @Roland you're prob right, it doesn't seems a perfect match to SO. would I have the chance to get a solution in R there? Anyway, I just posted this to make "room" for your comment and @Vincent Zoonekynd answer in my previous question (which was originally related only to discover the cause of getting the `NA` using `cor`)

Comment: The chance to get code over there is high, but even if you don't get code you could always ask for help with the implementation here.

Comment: If you do ask on CrossValidated, you might want to reword the title slightly. "Robust" has a specific connotation in statistics, which is different to how you've used it here (roughly speaking, it refers to "noisy" data with lots of outliers).

Comment: @HongOoi if I receive a good answer here in the minutes and (especially) if it is no voted to be migrated I'd prefer not to move. Just because I don't need anything advanced and mainly cause I don't have the time to "reshape" the question now

Comment: Try normalizing the data before running the principal components.

Comment: Hm, I forgot that PCA isn't scale-invariant by default: variables with larger numerical variance will have a greater impact on the results. @shujaa: the problem is that normalising the data involves dividing by the variances, which defeats the purpose of the question. I'm not sure if there's any simple method that is both scale-invariant _and_ can be used for data with zero variance.

Comment: @HongOoi what about re-scaling all the curves in the ranges [0-1] (or `x/max(x)`, I know it's rude) before applying `prcomp`. would be still meaningful?

Comment: The problem is that it still assumes you have some kind of scale to start with. Can't rescale to a range of [0-1] if your starting range is 0.

Comment: @HongOoi Perhaps we need to pre-process then. If the range of one variable is 0, then the points *are* in a straight line, and the OP stated "My aim is to define a function which gives 1 for points perfectly aligned (regardless the slope)", thus no variance in one variable (or both) results in output of 1. If there is variance in both, then normalize and run principal components.

Comment: (continued) this also illustrates a potential problem that the OP needs to consider (making sure you know what you're asking for, that is). In most cases a 45 degree line is a strong relation, and a vertical or horizontal line as no relation, however the goal here is to call them all a strong relation.

Answer (score 6):

You could use [principal components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis), or more specifically, the proportion of total variance explained by the first principal component. This is equivalent to fitting the line that minimises the sum of squares of the orthogonal distances of points to the line, as opposed to vertical distances (which is what correlations do).

This can be done in R with either the `prcomp` or `princomp` function.

```
m <- cbind(1:10, rep(10, 10))
sdev <- prcomp(m)$sdev
sdev[1]/sum(sdev)
```

Comment: seems quite simple (few lines) and powerful! I'll have to test with some real data later! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

How about using the R-squared (or adjusted R-Squared) of a regression? After all, an R-squared is simply the square of the sample correlation coefficient.

```
reg.data1 <-lm(data1$value~data1$date)
summary(reg.data1)$adj.r.squared
#[1] 0.1844582

reg.data2 <-lm(data2$value~data2$date)
summary(reg.data2)$adj.r.squared
#[1] 0.9848801
```

Comment: This doesn't work if either the x or y variable has zero variance; see the link in the OP. That was what led to this question being posted: Michele is after something that works even with a zero-variance variable.

Comment: Also, note that while `lm(y~x)` will often give a sensible-looking R-square when `y` is constant, this is misleading, as it's really 0/0.

Comment: Also, though not explicitly stated, my guess is the OP wants an answer that is symmetric. But the R^2 of `y~x` is different from the R^2 of `x~y`.